# Accessing environment variables from within a recipe in GNU make in windwos

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to set an environment variable in windows and access the same within a recipe windows make. 
The general code goes something like this:

```
$(foreach i, $(SHORTCUT_TARGETS), $(eval $(call BUILD_ARTIFACT,$(i),$(param1),$(param2))))

define BUILD_ARTIFACT

    Rule: Prerequisites
        @echo Building : $(1)
        $(if $(filter $(1),string), ,setx LAST $(1) )
        $(if $(filter $(1),string),\
        @echo path-%LAST%,\
        @echo path-$(1)

endef
```

When I run this, the setx command is executed successfully, generally giving an output "SUCCESS: Specified value was saved."
But the output of the echo will be path-%LAST% as opposed to an output with the environment variable replaced in. I have tried it from cmd and powershell and I've gotten the same output in both cases. 
I have also tried replacing setx with set and export, neither approaches produced a positive result.

Comment: To clarify, when I said I tried export, I meant wrapped in an $(eval...) block, this isn't the behavior I am looking for as I need the command to be executed only on the build as such and the eval will be parsed by the makefile for all targets in SHORTCUT_TARGETS instead of just the one I have specified.

Comment: Well, the first thing is you have to define the variable `BUILD_ARTIFACT` _BEFORE_ you use it in the `foreach` loop.  Currently, that foreach loop does nothing because the result of each `call` function is the empty string.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your post to show an executable makefile that exhibits your problem.